# If inside the Org-wide setting we define to block accessing sharepoint sites from un-managed devices, then can we allow it inside certain sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration

Inside the Organization wide setting >> we define to block access for sharepoint site using un-managed, as follow:-

[image]

Then can we allow accessing sharepoint from un-managed devices inside certain site collections? or if we want to allow un-managed access for at least one site collection then we should allow it inside the Organization settings?

now in the official docs Microsoft mentioned the following:-

> . If you have configured the organization-wide policy, the site-level
> setting you specify must beat least as restrictive as the
> organization-level setting.

but i am not sure what this exactly means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that the site level cannot be more *open* than the tenant level setting. I.e. you cannot block at a tenant but allow for a specific site.